# How to create a recurrent event where every instance is individually modifiable

Tags: sharepoint-online, lookup-column, sharepoint-calendar

I have a calendar web part that is associated to another list (Projects).
Now, each event in the calendar web part has a lookup column from the "Projects" list.

My problem is that when I create a recurrent event in the calendar I can't associate each instance of it to a different "Project".

Thank you for your help.